# Clarification / Examples on ServiceStack Authentication

Tags: session, authentication, memcached, servicestack

I'm trying to get to grips with ServiceStack to build a new mobile product with it.  It's slowly coming together but the documentation, although good, is a little brief in parts with no facility for comments & questions.

**This question is about the built-in authentication.**

I have been working from the SocialBootstrap, which is a great example, though my lack of experience with backbone is a bit of a hindrance. I'd like to learn it at the same time but don't have the time to do that so want to continue with traditional views.

Based on this there are some samples or documentation extensions that would be really useful.

**1. Why are all the properties on `AuthUserSession` strings?**
I have seen via the `CustomUserSession` class that you can create a `CustomId` though shouldn't a default property map to the `AutoIncrement` property of a database table?  Having to parse to an integer is not really ideal. I suppose it's only done once but still seemed odd.

```cs
var user = session.TranslateTo<User>();
user.Id = int.Parse(session.UserAuthId);
```

**2. Retrieving the session**
My controllers derive from `ControllerBase`  which implements `ServiceStackController<CustomUserSession>`, so getting to the session from controllers is easy with `base.UserSession`. If I need to access the session in the `View` then I simply stuff the session in a `ViewBag` property.

My services extend `AppServiceBase`, at the moment the only way I've been able to access the session is by injecting the `ClientCache`:

```cs
public ICacheClient CacheClient { get; set; }
```

And then calling:

```cs
var userSession = SessionFeature.GetOrCreateSession<AuthUserSession>(CacheClient);
```

This doesn't seem the most elegant of solutions so I hope there is a better way that I don't know of.  Which leads onto..

**3. IClientCache**
From reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817171/servicestack-authentication) it sounds like I need to implement a more persistent session cache. It's quite annoying having to authenticate every time I recompile, save `_layout`, or any other app resetting action.

Would the recommended solution for more persistent caching be to use Memcached? Unfortunately in the past I have only worked with FormsAuthentication so this again is new territory.

```cs
container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemcachedClientCache("127.0.0.0[:11211]");
```

**4. Manual Registration**
This is a weird one.  I was trying to code without an internet connection so I implemented manual registration to avoid having to comment out all the `[Authenticate]` attributes on my controllers (the views also have some logged in logic).

It worked, or I recall it working as I could continue debugging. However now back in the connected world it doesn't.  And the API endpoint seems to not exist.  If I browse to `/api/register` then I receive a `NotImplementedException`. Again, as I'm not using backbone I have a javascript function to perform the work:

```js
var gateway = new servicestack.ClientGateway(location.protocol + "//" + location.host + '/api/');

function intiRegisterUser() {
    $('#signup-button').click(function () {
        gateway.postFormDataToService({
                Register: {
                    userName: $('#Username').val(),
                    displayName: $('#Username').val(),
                    firstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
                    lastName: $('#LastName').val(),
                    email: $('#Email').val(),
                    password: $('#Password').val()
                }
            },
            function(e) {
                document.location = "/";
            },
            function(ex) {
                handleError(ex);
            });
    });
}
```

This also returns a `NotImplementedException`.

This documentation page is great btw, but could be extended a bit to include some of this.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Why are all the properties on AuthUserSession strings?**

[ServiceStack's built-in Authentication](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) was designed to support multiple Auth Repository and Session provider back-ends. To be able to support multiple providers and to reduce the friction required in creating new providers many *metadata properties* remain as strings which can hold any data type (as opposed to int's which can only hold 32bit integers).

**2. Retrieving the session**

When using [ServiceStack's New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) you can inherit from the convenient [Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Service.cs) base class which lets you access the typed UserAuthSession with:

```
base.SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
```

It also provides access to the dynamic Session bag with:

```
base.Session["dynamicProperty"]
```

**3. IClientCache**

If you want a permanent cache, use any of [ServiceStack's distributed cache providers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching). I recommend Redis which [holds many advantages over Memcached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net/2760282#2760282) and is [easy to get running in Windows with Vagrant](https://github.com/JasonPunyon/redishobo):

**4. Manual Registration**

The `/api/register` service [only implements HTTP POST](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/RegistrationService.cs#L97). Whilst the [custom route for the Registration Service is /register](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/RegistrationFeature.cs#L17) the [pre-defined route](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#predefinedroutes) for the RegistrationService (which your example is using) is inferred by the [Registration Request DTO](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/RegistrationService.cs#L15) which is:

```
/api/json/syncreply/Registration
```

or [as of v3.9.35 release](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes), the shorter alias:

```
/api/json/reply/Registration
```

So your javascript example needs to use the **Registration** property, e.g:

```
 gateway.postFormDataToService({
    Registration: { .. }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.  I assumed the UserId string property would be for this reason.  Maybe it's in the documentation & I skipped it.   Service session retrieval is much better, thanks!   Will have a look at Redis, I was planning on looking at that to replace my database anyway.  As for the registration, I forgot to mention that I had tried with 'Registration:' and it returns the same NotImplementedException.  I had also browsed to /api/json/syncreply/Registration - this also displays a NotImplementedException.   I am on v3.9.33.0